# JavaScript recursion odd behaviour?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, recursion, closures

I'm having trouble understanding why a recursive function I wrote in JavaScript is having issues. When I feed it a large json file, it gets caught in an endless loop. I have a feeling it has something to do with how JavaScript closures work. Hopping some one smart can look at my code and explain what is going on.

I've ported the function line for line to PHP and it produces the output I expect.

JavaScript:

```
var jsonfile = process.argv[2];

json = require("./"+jsonfile);

path = "2";

buildPaths(json, path);

function buildPaths(json, path) {

    if (json.Children == null || json.Children.length == 0) {

        console.log(path + "/" + json.TypedItemId);

    } else {

        for (i = 0; i < json.Children.length; i++) {
            buildPaths(json.Children[i], path + "/" + json.TypedItemId);
        }
    }

}
```

Ported to PHP:

```
<?php
$jsonfile = $argv[1];
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($jsonfile));

$path = "2";

buildPaths($json, $path);

function buildPaths($json, $path) {


    if ($json->Children == null || count($json->Children) == 0) {

        echo $path . "/" . $json->TypedItemId . "\n";

    } else {

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($json->Children); $i++) {
            buildPaths($json->Children[$i], $path . "/" . $json->TypedItemId);
        }
    }

}
```

Sample JSON file for testing with ( larger files cause even more weirdness ):

```
{
  "TypedItemId": 4,
  "Children": [
    {
      "TypedItemId": 67,
      "Children": [
        {
          "TypedItemId": 90,
          "Children": [
            {
              "TypedItemId": 90,
              "Children": [
                {
                  "TypedItemId": 67,
                  "Children": [
                    {
                      "TypedItemId": 90,
                      "Children": [
                        {
                          "TypedItemId": 90,
                          "Children": []
                        },
                        {
                          "TypedItemId": 908,
                          "Children": []
                        }
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "TypedItemId": 908,
                      "Children": [
                        {
                          "TypedItemId": 90,
                          "Children": []
                        },
                        {
                          "TypedItemId": 908,
                          "Children": []
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "TypedItemId": 908,
              "Children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "TypedItemId": 908,
          "Children": [
            {
              "TypedItemId": 90,
              "Children": []
            },
            {
              "TypedItemId": 908,
              "Children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

PHP Output ( correct ):

```
2/4/67/90/90/67/90/90
2/4/67/90/90/67/90/908
2/4/67/90/90/67/908/90
2/4/67/90/90/67/908/908
2/4/67/90/908
2/4/67/908/90
2/4/67/908/908
```

JavaScript Node output ( incorrect ) :

```
2/4/67/90/90/67/90/90
2/4/67/90/90/67/90/908
```

Comment: you don't have any closures in your JS code. just a normal function.

Comment: Ok ty

still curious as to what is happening that is causing different output. Im wondering what it is about JavaScript that I don't understand that is causing the results I am seeing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your JavaScript, except for the iterator you are using in your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < json.Children.length; i++) {
```

Instead of declaring a local variable using `var` you are using a property `i` on the global object as an iterator, which is shared between all calls of `buildPaths`.

Use a local variable instead:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.Children.length; i++) {
```

Try it yourself:

```js
var json = {"TypedItemId":4,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":67,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":67,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[]}]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[]}]}]}]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[]}]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[{"TypedItemId":90,"Children":[]},{"TypedItemId":908,"Children":[]}]}]}]};

var path = "2";

buildPaths(json, path);

function buildPaths(json, path) {
    if (json.Children == null || json.Children.length == 0) {
        console.log(path + "/" + json.TypedItemId);
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < json.Children.length; i++) {
            buildPaths(json.Children[i], path + "/" + json.TypedItemId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: brilliant!! The i was a global variable LOL. Testing it now. Ty =)

Comment: To easily catch these types of mistakes, make sure enable strict mode with `use strict`.

Comment: Yup that did it! Thanks for being my code review eyes.

Comment: `"use strict";` would have saved you

Comment: Thanks guys, 2 important lessons. "use strict"; for more error messages, and always declare all your variables. Saw a speech once that recommended declaring variables at the top of the function al a C style when writing JavaScript to save yourself headaches. I totally listened and took it in and was like yes yes. But you never learn truly till you do it yourself =)